# VBA: Macro to loop through rows and Autofill

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: If I instead wanted to autofill these cells, would the following code work?

```
Sub BC_Edit()

    ' Define width and height of table

    Dim datasetWidth, datasetHeight As Integer

    ' Find values for width and height of table
    datasetWidth = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    datasetHeight = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ' Loop over each column
    For x = 1 To datasetWidth
        Set sourceRange = Cells(2,x)
        Set fillRange = Range(Cells(3, x), Cells(datasetHeight, x))
        sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange        
    Next

End Sub
```

---

I'm working with a couple of extremely large datasets - each approximately 3000 rows by 4000 columns. While Excel may not be the best tool for the job, I have already built a significant amount of infrastructure around the data and cannot move to a different framework. I'm using Excel 2007.

In a particular worksheet, when I try to Autofill using a formula I have inputted for the entire second column B (3000 x 1) via copy and paste of this column into the remaining 3000 by 3998 selection, or some part of this selection, Excel gives me a memory/resources error. So I would like to instead loop through each row and Autofill across all the columns. (In other words, I'd like to use A2 to autofill A3:A4000, B2 to autofill B3:B4000, and so on.) Perhaps this would help with the memory issue. How would I go about writing a macro to accomplish this?

I'd appreciate any advice on this issue, and perhaps some help with the appropriate VBA code, if possible.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share the formula? Is it complex? I just thought that the best possible approach to get what you want will differ based on the complexity of the formula to be written.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty basic example of a macro to set columns below 2 to the formula of column 2.
It would be best to have this attached to a button or something similar rather than running every time you open the sheet.

```
Sub Button_Click()
    ' Define width and height of table
    Dim datasetWidth, datasetHeight As Integer

    ' Find values for width and height of table
    datasetWidth = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    datasetHeight = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ' Loop over each column
    For x = 1 To datasetWidth
        ' From row 3 to the height of data, set the formula of the cells to
        ' the formula contained in row 2 of that column
        Range(Cells(3, x), Cells(datasetHeight, x)).Formula = Cells(2, x).Formula
    Next

End Sub
```